# iOS touchesMoved forwarded only once by UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, touchesmoved, touchesended

My goal, having at the same time, both:

- a UIButton that handle an event (`.touchDown`)
- another view upper in the hierarchy (i.e.: super) that receives a `touchBegan/Moved/Ended/Cancelled`.

I want that event because, I need the touch force and other stuff for some computing

---

In the upper/super view, I override the touchesBegan and friends, so that I can get forces and stuff.

BUT, basically, a UIButton doesn't forward a touch event, so (in this example) I extend UIButton (in my code I extend a subclass~ but that doesn't change the problem) and override the touchesBegan and friends, and add `next?.touchesBegan(...)` to it.

---

What works:

- `touchesBegan(...)` forwards to the super view correctly

What does not work:

- `touchesMoved(...)` only **forward ONCE** to its `super` views. (even tho the button's `touchesMoved` is called and that `next?` is not `nil`
- `touchesEnded(...)` is **NOT CALLED** when a `touchesMoved(...)` has been called before (only one touchesMoved(...) call if you follow). and again `next?` is not `nil`

```swift
// One of the overrided UIButton touches event
extension UIButton {
    open override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Button: touches began - ")
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        if next == nil { print("next was nil!") }
        print("Button: touches began - end\n")
    }
}

// One of the overrided ViewController touches event
// (which is only called once for touchesMoved, and then touchesEnded not called)
extension ViewController {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("ViewController: touches began - ")
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        print("ViewController: touches began - end\n")
    }
}
```

[Here is an example project to show you the problem](https://bitbucket.org/5t4rrk/problemtouchmovedonlyonce/src/main/):

- `git clone git@bitbucket.org:5t4rrk/problemtouchmovedonlyonce.git`

---

If someone has any insights about why is this behavioring like this, please let me know \o/

Answer (score 0):

I tried a slightly different approach using a subclass of a `UIGestureRecognizer`. See the code below based on your example project. Interesting it seems the UIButton is checking for the state `.begin` which the touchesBegan is setting. It might be possible to change your code to not set the state in the `touchesBegan` method. See if this works for you.

The UIKit gesture recognizers also give you a few delegate methods and the option to use a selector which has access to the state set by the touches... methods. But they don't give you that much information for each individual touch.

Sources:

[developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touche](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/implementing_a_custom_gesture_recognizer/implementing_a_continuous_gesture_recognizer)
[developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer)

[raywenderlich.com/6747815-uigesturerecognizer-tu](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6747815-uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-getting-started)

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTouched), for: .touchDown)
        
        let gesture = CustomGesture()
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    
    @objc
    func buttonTouched(button:UIButton) {
        print("Button ACTION!")
    }
}

class CustomGesture: UIGestureRecognizer {
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        print("ViewController: touches began")
        //  state = .began //Do not set the state to .began as this seems to be blocking the UIButton gesture.
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event!)
        for _ in touches {
            print("ViewController: touches moved")
        }
        state = .changed
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event!)
        print("ViewController: touches ended")
        state = .ended
    }
    
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event!)
        print("ViewController: touches cancelled")
        state = .cancelled
    }
}
```